# Copy/Migrate FileVault 2 encrypted hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, filevault, encryption, migration

I'm running OS X Mavericks and have the entire hard drive encrypted with FileVault 2. I intend to upgrade to a larger hard drive (actually an SSD). In the past when not using FileVault, I used Carbon Copy Cloner to copy the entire disk to the new hard drive. Can this be accomplished with a FileVault protected drive?

Answer (score 1):

SSD is different, it needs a separate driver from OS to work properly. It is better that you archive your drive using time machine, install OS X as usual and than, during the last install step, restore your home directory. This will ensure that your system uses all correct drivers and your SSD will live a healthier life.

When archiving with time machine, you can drag /System into the exclusion list to avoid archiving OS X itself (you'll be reinstalling it).